# Azure App Service 502.5 error response when loading a certificate using X509Certificate2

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-1.1

I have a .NET Core application that I'm trying to deploy to Azure App Service. When I deploy and try to load the site I'm getting a 502.5 error response. From what I've read that means it's a permissions issue. I've tried printing the logs with stdout, but while it physically creating the log files, they are all empty.

So I started eliminating the problem by commenting out code. On `ConfigureServices` I'm loading a certificate:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2("mycertificate.pfx", "**********");
```

If I comment out this line, then the application loads. Once returned it gives the error again.

From console in the Azure portal I've tried giving `mycertificate.pfx` permissions using `chmod 777 mycertificate.pfx`, but it didn't seem to have any affect.

I'm not sure if the problem is loading that specific file or using `X509Certificate2` at all.

How can I set it up to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I set it up to work?

1.Upload pfx Certificate to the Azure with [azure portal](https://portal.azure.com). It is required service plan B or above. How to change service plan please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview)

[image]

2. Add an App setting named WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES with its value set to the thumbprint of the certificate will make it accessible to your web application.

> You can have multiple comma-separated thumbprint values or can set this value to “ * “ (without quotes) in which case all your certificates will be loaded to your web applications personal certificate store

[image]

3.Access from WebApp

```
   using System;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;namespace UseCertificateInAzureWebsiteApp
    {
      class Program
      {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
          certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
          X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
                                     X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                                     // Replace below with your cert's thumbprint
                                     “E661583E8FABEF4C0BEF694CBC41C28FB81CD870”,
                                     false);
          // Get the first cert with the thumbprint
          if (certCollection.Count > 0)
          {
            X509Certificate2 cert = certCollection[0];
            // Use certificate
            Console.WriteLine(cert.FriendlyName);
          }
          certStore.Close();
        }
      }
    }
```

We could get more info from [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/?v=17.23h).